# Adding parentheses in ggplot2 within ylab text that contains other characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a y-axis label that is: `µ (d^-1)`. So far, I have:

`ylab(expression(mu~d^{-1}))`

but I cannot figure out how to get the parentheses before the `d` and after the `super-scripted 1` to make this complete.

Comment: What's wrong with `ylab(expression(mu~(d^{-1})))`?

Comment: try `ylab(TeX('$\\mu~d^{-1}$'))` from {latex2exp} for typical TeX style